# ws-c3750x-48pf-s v02 not booting after password reset procedure

Tags: cisco, switch

I tried to do a Password Reset Procedure on ws-c3750x-48pf-s v02 - 48-Port PoE, but at the end of the procedure the switch no longer works after multiple restarts and pressing the mode key, I always have in serial console only these three lines

```
Base ethernet MAC Address: d4:8c:b5:d1:cc:00
Xmodem file system is available.
The password-recovery mechanism is enabled
```

And nothing after an hour
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Have you used this procedure: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-2950-series-switches/12040-pswdrec-2900xl.html ?

Comment: Also, [that switch is EoL](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/catalyst-3560-x-series-switches/eos-eol-notice-c51-736139.html), and you need to replace it with something that is supported.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your answers, I solved the problem which came from a defective mode button.
The switch works fine, except I got this message on startup, it doesn't seem to affect the switch but I don't know how to fix it.
Thank you

Loading "c3750e-universalk9-mz.150-2.SE6.bin"...c3750e-universalk9-mz.150-2.SE6.bin: no such device

Error loading "c3750e-universalk9-mz.150-2.SE6.bin"

Comment: Please accept your answer so that the question does not keep popping up, looking for an answer.

Comment: Only the first sentence provides an answer, the rest is another question.